# Silverlight datagrid fails to display data

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I have a datagrid defined in my project's XAML:

```
        <data:DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="gridOfferings"
                       Margin="10,10,10,10" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding Trader}"
                DisplayIndex="0"
                Header="Trader" 
                Width="Auto"
                FontSize="11"/>
            <data:DataGridTextColumn 
                Binding="{Binding Product}"
                DisplayIndex="1"
                Header="Product" 
                Width="Auto"
                FontSize="11"/>
            </data:DataGrid.Columns>
        </data:DataGrid>
```

I bind it to a List<> of custom objects:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _Rows = new List<OfferingRowData>();

        _Rows.Add(new OfferingRowData()
        {
            Trader = "Kameilya Loenstein",
            Product = "American Consolidated AAA",
            Price = 24.95,
            OfferingMade = DateTime.Now
        });

        _Rows.Add(new OfferingRowData()
        {
            Trader = "Bill Foobar",
            Product = "IBM Mid-Atlantic Exotic",
            Price = 204.90,
            OfferingMade = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-3)
        });

        gridOfferings.ItemsSource = _Rows;

    }
```

When it shows up on the page, the column headers appear, but none of the data does.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing works fine for me, have you got any more info?  Are you actually doing what you have posted above?

Comment: What version of Silverlight is this?

Comment: @Anthony, this is my actual code. @Jeff, it's Silverlight 3.0.

Comment: In that case I can't explain why it doesn't work, dumped your code into an empty user control and run it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

Trying using an `ObservableCollection<T>` instead of a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, this problem disappeared when I stripped the BubbleCreamTheme off of my page.